# Having trouble with CSS layouts, inline-blocks

Tags: html, css, layout

Am practicing positioning and cannot figure out why my margins cause my section to to go down, instead of staying inline with the aside. I have read about the overflow function as well as vertical-align: top, yet both do not seem to work. Give me tips, or correct code. Also, there is no space between the aside and section.

```css
header,
aside,
section,
footer {
  background-color: skyblue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px 1px 2px 1px;
}
aside {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: auto;
}
section {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>(header)</header>

<aside>(aside)</aside>
<section>(section)</section>

<footer>(footer)</footer>
```

Comment: Try removing the ' in the first line of code, maybe this could be the problem. In this case, the browser may not be correctly interpreting your CSS.

Comment: Please add the HTML for this; we can't do much to help debug with only the CSS and no way to see what's happening.

Comment: Added HTML, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
section, aside {
  margin: 2px 1px 2px 1px;
}
aside {
  width: 30%;
}
section {
  width: 70%;
}
```

`70%` + `30%` + `1px` + `1px` (margins on the `aside`) + `1px` + `1px` (margins on the section)

That adds up to more than `100%`. (4px more.) Meaning there's not enough room for these things to sit on the same line.

Remove the margins and you should be good to go. You can use either padding or transparent borders to create the spaces you need between elements. (Try just changing "margin" to "padding" in that first set of rules and see if that gets you what you want.)

Answer (score 0):

Because that's not how border-box works. Border-box does just that - incorporates **borders** in the total width. Since you're doing 30% + 70% on the aside and section, there is no room for margins. It's an easy fix, though:
Remove the margins, and add `border: 2px solid transparent;` Which will work exactly like margins. You can of course make them any color you want, and change the size of the borders if you want different widths on different sides.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another approach that solves your problem in another way, but I do not know if you can use it in your project.

```css
  header,
  aside,
  section,
  footer {
    background-color: skyblue;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  aside {
    width: 29%;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 1%;
  }
  
  section {
    width: 70%;
 float: right;
  }
```

```html
<aside></aside>
<section></section>
```

I hope to have helped in some way.

Comment: This removed my footer, maybe if I clearfixed something for this example

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above you are 4px wider than your screen width with your aside tag and section tag to account for this you can reduce the width percentage from 30 to 29.4%.

```
aside {
  width: 29.4%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

or

```
section {

width: 69.4%;

display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
overflow: auto;
}
```

or change the margins to accommodate.

```
header,
aside,
section,
footer {
  background-color: skyblue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

  margin: 2px -3px 2px 1px;
```

}